# position of ViewPager item with Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have implemented `ViewPager` with use of android Data Binding, it is working perfect with data and click events.

I have created `interface` for click event

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick();
}
```

Here is my `instantiateItem()` of `PagerAdapter`

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    ListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(mLayoutInflater, R.layout.list_item, container, false);
    binding.setHandler(itemClickListener);
    binding.getRoot().setTag(position);
    container.addView(binding.getRoot());
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

i am sending `itemClickListener` in adapter constructor.

```
public MatchListAdapter(Context context, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.itemClickListener= itemClickListener;
}
```

Here is my `list_item.xml`

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
           name="handler"
           type="com.example.ItemClickListener" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_viewItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onItemClick()}"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        //rest views and controls.

   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Now problem is that i want to pass **position of clicked item**, how to pass that position from xml? As i have called my method from xml how to pass position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass view in interface

```
 public interface ItemClickListener {
     public void onItemClick(View view);
  }
```

Than set position in tag which you already doing

```
binding.getRoot().setTag(position);
```

And than you can get position from that view param like this

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view){
  int position=(int)view.getTag();
}
```

For more detail info you can refer http://developers-club.com/posts/267735/

Comment: How can i get my view in xml?

Comment: `DataBinding` will handle that you don't need to pass any view params from xml.

Answer (score 4):

Both the answer helped me and both are working, i have found another way also, however its bit lengthy.

I have taken one more `Integer` variable in my `list_item.xml` and setting its value from adapter.

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="position"
        type="Integer"/>
</data>
```

and passing it in `onItemClick`

```
android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onItemClick(position)}"
```

then interface will look like this

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

will be setting value of position from `instantiateItem()`

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    ListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(mLayoutInflater, R.layout.list_item, container, false);
    binding.setHandler(itemClickListener);
    binding.setPosition(position);
    binding.getRoot().setTag(position);
    container.addView(binding.getRoot());
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Comment: I think my answer is more reliable and less complicated.

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid yes i know, that is why i have written my answer is bit lengthy

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters in the lambda expression, like this:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onItemClick(rootItemView.getTag().toString())}"
```

And of course you'll need to edit your interface method and its implementations:

```
public void onItemClick(String data);
```