# how to get position of recylerview databinding

Tags: android-databinding

i am using data binding recycler view .i want to get that clicked position and show that position id(image) in view pager.i created data binding XML for image.

Comment: you can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463100/position-of-viewpager-item-with-data-binding/), it might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position of clicked view does not matter, because views reused again and again while you scrolling content. You can directly set **EventLisener** to **ViewHolder** at `onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position)` method of RecyclerView.Adapter class